# Redirect traffic from site B to site A, change browser address

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am planning to redirect `siteB.com` and `siteB.net` to `siteA.com`. (`siteB.com/.net` is an overlay of `siteA.com` and will have no actual content.)

I want visitors to `siteB.com` and `siteB.net` to be redirected to `siteA.com` in the browser address bar, because the domain names for `siteB.com` and `siteB.net` are being phased out and will exist in name only. Existing links out in the wild, however, will continue to need redirects for some time.

Can someone please check my .htaccess rules and see if I got it right?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^siteB\.(com|net) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.siteA.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error? That works fine for me. You'll need to make sure that stuff is **before** the wordpress rewrite rules.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Just checking to see if there are any issues with .htaccess (or a better way of doing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only suggestion is add a **$** at the end of `(com|net)` so that it won't match something like **siteB.commerce.com**, not that you'd be likely to get requests for that domain. And maybe bound the RewriteRule match to `^(.*)$`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^siteB\.(com|net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.siteA.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong... I still don't get what is the difference between **`^(.*)$`**, which catches everything and **`(.*)`**, which... catches everything too! They both are exactly the same in this context (= when used *alone*).

Comment: There's no difference in this context at all. Just a matter of completion: for example, if the site gets upgraded later and a small change needs to be appended to the regular expression, a **(.*)** might get changed to **site/(.*)** in a hurry, and unwittingly match "/othersite/path/file.html", whereas with the ^/$ in place will avoid future confusion.